# Error message "Topic not present in metadata after 180000 ms" in Kafka broker with SCRAM security mechanism using kafka-docker-playground

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have setup a kafka broker based on SASL SCRAM mechanism by using the kafka-docker-playgorund available at https://github.com/vdesabou/kafka-docker-playground. This uses confluent kafka. I am using Ubuntu VM to run this broker. I have used the start.sh script to run the docker compose file available under /environment/sasl-scram folder. This setup uses SASL_PLAINTEXT (without SSL). The server is running without any issues. I am able to create topics and send message to this broker using the control centre UI interface, which is part of the kafka-docker-playground. The only issue I am facing is while trying to connect to this broker from the java code. I keep seeing the following exception.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException:
> Topic testtopic not present in metadata after 180000 ms

Following is the Java code.

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;

import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaProducerapp {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String topic = "testtopic";
        Properties props = new Properties();


        props.put("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092");
 

        props.put("group.id", "test");

        props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256");
        props.put("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
        props.put("retries", "2700000");
        props.put("retry.backoff.ms=1000", "2700000");
        props.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"" + "client" + "\" password=\"" + "client-secret" + "\";");
        props.put("retry.backoff.ms","1000");
        props.put("batch.size","131072");
        props.put("buffer.memory","66554432");
        props.put("compression.type","snappy");
        props.put("acks","all");
        props.put("linger.ms","100");
        props.put("request.timeout.ms","60000");
        props.put("enable.idempotence","true");
        props.put("delivery.timeout.ms","180300");
        props.put("metadata.max.idle.ms","60000");
        props.put("metadata.max.age.ms","60000");
        props.put("max.block.ms","180000");




        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

        try {
            // Send a message to the Kafka topic
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, "Hello, Kafka!")).get();
            System.out.println("testing");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception occured");
        }
    }
}
```